# Mapping Values Using XSL 3.0 accumulators

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0, accumulator

I need to transform following xml as **Expected Output** using xsl 3.0 accumulators.

**Input XML:**

```
<AggregatedData>
   <Data>
      <Entry>
         <legacyID>ABC</legacyID>
         <legacyLocation>Test_Loc1,Test_Loc2</legacyLocation>
         <AssociateID>123</AssociateID>
      </Entry>
      <Entry>
         <legacyID>ABC</legacyID>
         <legacyLocation>Test_Loc3</legacyLocation>
         <AssociateID>123</AssociateID>
      </Entry>
      <Entry>
         <legacyID>CDE</legacyID>
         <legacyLocation>Test_Loc4,Test_Loc5</legacyLocation>
         <AssociateID>456</AssociateID>
      </Entry>
   </Data>
   <root>
      <row>
         <legacyID>ABC</legacyID>
         <legacyLocation>Test_Loc1</legacyLocation>
         <company>Test Company 1</company>
         <firstname>Test1</firstname>
      </row>
      <row>
         <legacyID>CDE</legacyID>
         <legacyLocation>Test_Loc5</legacyLocation>
         <company>Test Company 2</company>
         <firstname>Test2</firstname>
      </row>
   </root>
</AggregatedData>
```

Values under `<Data>` can contain comma separated values for `<legacyLocation>` and values under `<root>` only contains one value for `<legacyLocation>`. I need to map these values and get the output as the **Expected Output** below. Is there a way to map values using XSLT 3.0 accumulators using both **legacyID** and **legacyLocation**?

**Expected Output:**

```
<root>
   <worker>
      <row>
         <AssociateID>123</AssociateID>
         <legacyID>ABC</legacyID>
         <legacyLocation>Test_Loc1</legacyLocation>
         <company>Test Company 1</company>
         <firstname>Test1</firstname>
      </row>
      <row>
         <AssociateID>456</AssociateID>
         <legacyID>CDE</legacyID>
         <legacyLocation>Test_Loc5</legacyLocation>
         <company>Test Company 2</company>
         <firstname>Test2</firstname>
      </row>
   </worker>
</root>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Why the requirement to use accumulators and not keys?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Previously the requirement is only to use the legacyID for mapping but as for the example it's not a unique value. Mapping speed is the reason for use accumulators. Because there are nearly 4000+ records.

Comment: <AggregatedData>
<Data>
<Entry>
<legacyID>CDE</legacyID>
<legacyLocation>Test_Loc4,Test_Loc5,Test_Loc6</legacyLocation>
<AssociateID>456</AssociateID>
</Entry>
</Data>
<row>
<legacyID>CDE</legacyID>
<legacyLocation>Test_Loc5</legacyLocation>
<company>Test Company 2</company>
<firstname>Test2</firstname>
</row>
</root>
</AggregatedData>



The code is working as expected when we are trying to match first value from the legacyLocation node.But it's not picking the exact associate id when we need to match 'Test_Loc5'(a middle value) between row data and entry data.@MartinHonnen

Comment: Is the result at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbBfrFA not as intented? I had to fix your XML snippet from the comment.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Can you check this example https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNXUzJC/2

Comment: If there can be spaces before and/or after the comma make the `tokenize` call `tokenize('\s*,\s*')`.

Comment: Thank you for the help now it's working. Can you give me some references to learn XSLT? @MartinHonnen

Comment: Look into the resources and courses sections of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info for some resources to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a key like

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
  
  <xsl:key name="assoc-id" match="Entry" use="(legacyLocation => tokenize(',') => sort()) ! (current()/legacyID || ',' || .)"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/AggregatedData">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="root"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('assoc-id', (legacyID || ',' || legacyLocation))/AssociateID, node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I don't see why an accumulator would perform better, I would mainly try to use it if you to need to cross-reference with streaming.

A non-streaming use of an accumulator would be

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">
  
  <xsl:accumulator name="assoc-id" as="map(xs:string, xs:string)" initial-value="map{}">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule 
      match="Entry" 
      select="let $entry := . 
              return fold-left(legacyLocation => tokenize(',') => sort(), $value, function($a, $k) { map:put($a, $entry/legacyID || ',' || $k, $entry/AssociateID/string()) })"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>
  
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" use-accumulators="assoc-id"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/AggregatedData">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="root"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row">
    <xsl:copy>
      <AssociateID>{accumulator-before('assoc-id')(legacyID || ',' || legacyLocation)}</AssociateID>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```